# Python UDP recvfrom() specific address

Tags: python, networking, udp, recv

The problem I see with this code is that although it is working, some of the information clients(players) send to this server will end up at the method 'permission' when intended to end up at 'clientRequests', because both of them has recvfrom(). So, if I could specify WHICH addr I want information from as a parameter of recvfrom(), it would solve it. I believe it's possible with C++, but is it with python, and how?
With TCP this problem doesn't exist but I prefer UDP.

Something like: recvfrom(512, address=(ip, port)) ?

'permission' is used to handle new clients connecting.

The problem would be that information like positions, events sent from a client, will not be taken care of at 'permission'.

```
class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        #host = '192.168.0.2'
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 50007
        addr = (host, port)
        self.UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.UDPSock.bind(addr)
        self.UDPSock.settimeout(5.0)
        self.searchForClients = True
        self.playersOnline = []
        threading.Thread(target=self.permission).start()
        Gui.add_event("Server online on port %s" % port)


    def permission(self):
        global _status
        while self.searchForClients:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            _status.set("Status: Running; Connected: %s" % len(self.playersOnline))
            try:
                clientMessage, addr = self.UDPSock.recvfrom(1024) # , MSG_PEEK
            except:
                clientMessage = ""
            if clientMessage == "CONNECT" and addr not in self.playersOnline:                       
                if self.searchForClients:
                    self.addNewClient(addr)

            elif clientMessage == "DISCONNECT" and addr in self.playersOnline:
                self.removeClient(addr)

        Gui.add_event("No longer accepting logins")
        return False

    def clientRequests(self, addr):
        latestRequest = time.time()
        while addr in self.playersOnline:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            try:
                data, requestAddr = self.UDPSock.recvfrom(1024)
            except:
                requestAddr, data = "", ""
            if requestAddr == addr:
                latestRequest = time.time()
                dataCommand = data.split(':')
            if time.time() - latestRequest > 2:
                if addr in self.playersOnline:
                    self.removeClient(addr)

        if not self.searchForClients:       
            Gui.add_event("Player %s(%s) forcibly removed" % addr)
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that threads unnecessarily complicate simple UDP servers like this one. Just listen on the socket and dispatch the calls based on whether packet's source address has already been seen.

And no, regular [`recvfrom(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recvfrom.2.html) system call does not allow you to "filter" what address you get data from, only to get that information. Filtering is done with [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) on UDP socket, but that limits you to a single source per socket.

Comment: Well this is actually an online game project I'm having with friends, and it is important to have one thread for each client, and that one thread to listen only to that address :( PS What I've shown up there is obviously not the entire server class EDIT: I'm going to look up connect(2) thank you..

Comment: Just a suggestion - try thinking about the game in terms of a state machine. You might find that your assumption about having to have threads is false.